# Wildcard path to serve Static resources

Tags: nginx

I want to access resources like images in a directory with the endpoint that has a token in middle of the path.

```
http://example.com/contextpath/<token>/logos/myLogo.png
```

`Example: http://example.com/contextpath/abc1234/logos/myLogo.png`

I am trying to configure it in nginx.conf and put this config to point the resource to a directory:

```
location ~ ^/contextpath/(logos/.*) {
    root      "C:/temp/logos";
}
```

But its not working.

Comment: The regular expression does not match your example URL. Are you trying to ignore the token or capture it?

Comment: @RichardSmith I want to capture it also, but if not possible Its ok to ignore it for now. As long as the resource will served.

Comment: Where is the file located in your example? `C:/temp/logos/myLogo.png` - with both `contextpath` and `<token>` removed?

Comment: @RichardSmith yes

Answer (score 0):

To deliver the file at `C:/temp/logos/myLogo.png` in response to the URL `http://example.com/contextpath/abc1234/logos/myLogo.png` (where the text token `abc1234` is unknown) you should use a regular expression `location` together with `try_files`.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/contextpath/[^/]+/logos(/.*)$ {
    root "C:/temp/logos";
    try_files $1 =404;
}
```

The `/[^/]+/` sequence matches any token between two `/`s.

The text "logos" should either appear in the capture or in the `root` statement - not both as in your example.

See [the `try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).